# Python Selenium Javascript Link Click Fails to Execute

Tags: python, selenium

I am using Selenium for Python with the PhantomJS Ghost Driver in order to click links which have Javascript in the href, such as the links from [this](https://structuredginniemaes.ginnienet.com/Download/) link.  I can get the link just fine as an element, but when I try to click it, things go wrong.  Here's some code (note - url is a list, where the first element is the Jscript link and the second is the link text)

```
def get_jscript_down(self,url):
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    print(self.exact_url)
    driver.get(self.exact_url)
    elements = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
    for ele in elements:
        if ele.text == url[1].encode("utf-8").replace("  "," "):
            break
    ele.click()
    print("Cannot yet download %s" % url)

    return False
```

Everything works as I need it to except for ele.click().  When I execute that, I get an ugly looking WebDriverException.

`selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: u'Error Message => \'Click failed: ReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: __doPostBack\'\n caused by Request => {"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"81","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:34441","User-Agent":"Python-urllib/2.6"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"sessionId\": \"71c20b50-ca21-11e2-a03c-f58c49e5a1bc\", \"id\": \":wdc:1370025577147\"}","url":"/click","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"click","directory":"/","path":"/click","relative":"/click","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/click","queryKey":{},"chunks":["click"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/71c20b50-ca21-11e2-a03c-f58c49e5a1bc/element/%3Awdc%3A1370025577147/click"}' ; Screenshot: available via screen`

I'm not really sure why this click is failing.  As far as I have read, I should be okay using click in that way.  Below is the relevant portion of the stack trace (from right before things start breaking to the end)

```
line 283, in get_jscript_down
    ele.click()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 54, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 228, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 165, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 158, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
```

Any ideas will be much appreciated.  I'm fairly stumped.

Comment: You will probably have a faster, more reliable test if you use an xpath or css locator constructed dynamically based upon the URL instead of iterating over every a tag on the page.  The code will also be more readable.

Comment: While you are right about my test moving faster if I use another system, speed is not my main concern at the moment. My end goal is to make the code robust enough to handle most Javascript based links automatically.  Most of the time, I see Xpaths obtained by manually checking link information with something like Firebug, which is less robust than I would like.

I have to disagree with the readability note.  It seems like a "six-of-one" situation between reading xPaths and reading a small nested loop structure.  I do still need to add comments in, though.

Comment: An xpath or css locator can be read as "give me the element with the a tag that contains the text xxxx; click on it".  The loop reads "inspect each element with an a tag, if it contains text matching xxxx, exit the loop; click on whatever element we last checked in the loop".  The first is much easier to understand.  It will also give you an "element not found" error if the link doesn't exist or your identification methodology is wrong, whereas the loop will give you a much more obscure error about something not being clickable (or potentially, the JS error you see here).

Comment: Switched to an xpath system to see if it changed the error.  Sadly, the error did not change.  I also still disagree that it's more readable, since I don't think translating code into English is the way to judge readability, but I do love the compactness of the method.  I am putting the code on the end of the comment for those interested ||| driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='%s']" % url[1].encode("utf-8")).click() |||

Comment: So I dug around some, and it looks like PhantomJS and ASP.net don't always play well together, at least without some massaging.  I don't pretend to know much about either, so I hesitate to post an answer, but from what I've read, you may need to configure your server to properly recognize PhantomJS' abilities as a client, and also potentially run in to issues with JS run from certain constructs in the page itself.  Ultimately, it looks like the ASP.net JS isn't getting correctly loaded (__doPostBack is a JS method that should come from ASP.net).

Comment: I was afraid of that.  ASP.net has been the bane of my existence since I started this work of mine.  Thanks for finding that out, though!  At least I have a direction to take my work in now.

I'll keep the question open in case I get this sorted out, so I can answer it.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did a bit more reading - it appears that doPostBack is an obfuscation of just making a POST request.  I'm hoping to find a way to dissect what the script actually does to try and create a generalized case for  ASP.net nonsense.

Comment: Minor update - I think PyV8 may provide an answer to the issue.  doPostBack has the same format on any ASP website, so ideally I can use PyV8 to run the Javascript in the website's context.

How exactly I will accomplish that, and whether or not I can get PyV8 successfully installed on this crazy machine of mine, are different questions. I wanted to update the question with some progress, though, just to let folks who are suffering from the same problems know.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error when clicking "Privatperson" on [this page](http://dustin.no). The button has id 'btnSelectB2C'. What I ended up doing was using submit on the element:

```
driver.find_element(:id, 'btnSelectB2C').submit
```

(This is Ruby code, but I assume it should be trivial to adapt if it is applicable in your case.)

Comment: Sorry for the long delay in any response.  That portion of the project has long since been put aside.  I'll take a look at this when I can and let you know how it goes, though!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `ele.click()` is not in the loop.

Try this:

```
def get_jscript_down(self,url):
    try:
        driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    except:
        print("[ERROR] Your Browser Have a problem")
    print(self.exact_url)
    try:
        driver.get(self.exact_url)
    except:
        print("[ERROR] Check Your Internet Connection , Cannot Open \"{0}\"".format(self.exact_url))
    try:
        elements = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
    except:
        print("[ERROR] Cannot Find Elements")
    for elem in elements:
        if elem.text == url[1].encode("utf-8").replace("  "," "):
            break
        else:
            elem.click()
    print("Cannot yet download {0}".format(url))
    return False
```