# Python crawler to get DOM info by using Selenium and PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, selenium, phantomjs

I used **Selenium** and **PhantomJS** hoping to get data from a website which using javascript to build the DOM.

The simple code below works, but it's not always valid. I meant that most of time it would return an empty website which didn't execute the javascript. It could seldom get the correct info I want.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://mall.pchome.com.tw/prod/QAAO6V-A9006XI59'
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS
driver.get(url)

print(driver.page_source, file=open('output.html','w'))

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"html5lib")
print(soup.select('#MetaDescription'))
```

It has a high probability to return an empty string :

```
[<meta content="" id="MetaDescription" name="description"/>]
```

Is the website server not allowing web crawlers? What can I do to fix my code?

What's more, all the info I need could be find in the `<head>` 's `<meta>`tag.
(Like showing above, the data has an id `MetaDescription`)

Or is there any simpler way to just get the data in `<head>` tag?

Comment: `soup.select('head')`? Anyway, have you tried to wait a little?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, `driver = webdriver.PhantomJS` is not a correct way to initialize a selenium webdriver in Python, replace it with:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
```

The symptoms you are describing are similar to when you have the timing issues. [Add a wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) to wait for the desired element(s) to be present *before trying to get the page source*:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get(url)

# waiting for presence of an element
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#MetaDescription")))

print(driver.page_source, file=open('output.html','w'))

driver.close()

# further HTML parsing here
```

---

You may also need to [ignore SSL errors and set the SSL protocol to `any`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23581291/python-selenium-with-phantomjs-empty-page-source). In some cases, [pretending not be PhantomJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18433453/python-selenium-with-phantomjs-click-failed-referenceerror-cantt-find-varia/18433763#18433763) helps as well.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't consider the timing issues. However, the page has tags with empty content before loading. It uses javascript to fill in the blanks.
So I used `Implicit Waits` to replace the waiting part.

I also tried to use the two links at the same time, and it just succeed for few times.

Comment: @WenT okay, in that case it is just about choosing the right condition to wait for. For example, wait for presence of the product title: `#NickContainer`. Or, may be wait for the product `img` element to be present..

Comment: I used a `driver.implicitly_wait(30)` but in vain. However, I tried `time.sleep(5)` and it works!!! So it's actually cause by timing issues.
But the `implicitly waits` didn't work for me, do I use this in wrong way?
Whatever,  thanks for giving directions!!

Comment: @WenT `time.sleep()` is not something you should use, it is highly unreliable and most of the time you end up waiting more than you should. Please continue picking the right condition for the `wait.until()`, thanks..